# print value of variable (counter) BEFORE it is modified

Tags: counters

It sounds counter intuitive.
I have an exam sheet with n exercises. The maximum score that a student can have is scoreExi where i varies between 1 and n.
For simplicity, I consider n known (say 3 here).

I want to display the total number of points on the first page (the sum of `scoreEx1`, `scoreEx2`, `scoreEx3`).

How to do that?

Here is my MWE but my problem is that I will affect the values of `scoreEx1`, `scoreEx2`, `scoreEx3` in the middle of the document, i.e AFTER the first page where I want to total to display..

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{article}

\newcounter{scoreEx1}
\newcounter{scoreEx2}
\newcounter{scoreEx3}
\newcounter{totalEx}

\setcounter{scoreEx1}{0}
\setcounter{scoreEx2}{0}
\setcounter{scoreEx3}{0}
\setcounter{totalEx}{0}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{scoreEx1}{5}
\setcounter{scoreEx2}{10}
\setcounter{scoreEx3}{15}
\addtocounter{totalEx}{\value{scoreEx1}}
\addtocounter{totalEx}{\value{scoreEx2}}
\addtocounter{totalEx}{\value{scoreEx3}}
The maximum score is : \textbf{\the\value{totalEx} points}
 [

\end{document}
```

Normally, the line `\setcounter{scoreEx1}{5}` comes after the first page. I just gave something to start with.

I'm thinking of a double compilation, if ever it's possible to stock the value between both compilations. I have no idea!

Thanks in advance

Edit: by the way, if there's a smarter way to add the values of scoreExi, I'll appreciate you showing me how to do it. Thanks again

Comment: there are various exam packages which store such numbers: https://ctan.org/topic/exam. Or use https://ctan.org/pkg/totalcount

Comment: Besides the solutions mentioned in the duplicate you can also use `\refstepcounter` to expose the counter to `\label` (and incrementing by one): `maximum score: \ref{totalpoints} ... code to set counters ... \refstepcounter{totalEx}\label{totalpoints}`. A single command to add up all the counters (and subtract one because of the increment in `\refstepcounter`): `\setcounter{totalEx}{\numexpr\the\value{scoreEx1}+the\value{scoreEx2}+the\value{scoreEx3}-1\relax}`.

Comment: Actually I used the exam package, still figuring it out but I solved this specific problem, thank you very much for your answers.